# iterate through existing keys and update dictionary python

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple script that loops through strings, in this case dna sequences from a file, and computes word frequencies for each dna string (same list of words each time, new list of values).
My approach (see below) uses a dictionary to store the words as keys and the frequency of each word as a value, but I'm stuck trying to add new values (for each subsequent dna record) to existing keys.

Easy enough for record1 (something like "GTACGTACATTT..."), my dictionary looks like:

{'GTAC':'2','ATTT':1,....}

Then for any additional records in $foo, I'd like to update this dictionary (comprising the same keys):
{'GTAC':'2','1',...,'ATTT':1,0,...}

```
from Bio import SeqIO



def tetra_freq(sequence):
    counts = {}
    for record in SeqIO.parse(sequence, 'fasta'):
        newseq=record.seq
        for base1 in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
            for base2 in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
                for base3 in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
                    for base4 in ['A','T','G','C']:
                        tetranucleotide = base1 + base2 + base3 + base4
                        count = newseq.count(tetranucleotide)
                        if tetranucleotide in counts.keys():
                            counts.update(count)
                        else:
                            counts[tetranucleotide] = count


    print(counts)

tetra_freq('$foo')
```

Comment: Holy nesting, Batman!

Comment: The dictionary's `update` function requires a dictionary as input: `counts.update({tetranucleotide: count})`. Luckily this will either update OR create the key for you.

Comment: You can user itertools.product('ATGC', repeat=4) instead of that nasty nesting, for what it's worth.

Comment: thanks @JackGibbs, the nesting is based on a python primer for biologists that I found online.  Main obstacle remains..

Comment: @Thane Brimhall Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately that appears to only add the values from one record to the previous (i.e. {GTAC:1,TTAA:2} becomes {GTAC:2,TTAA:4} instead of {GTAC:1,1,TTAA:2,2}

Comment: Correct, I must've missed the fact you wanted to output *lists* of counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from your description whether you are only looking at four-letter-aligned words, ie

```
"GTACGTACATTT" => "GTAC", "GTAC", "ATTT"
```

(as your dictionary-count implies), or whether you are looking at any four-letter sequence,

```
"GTACGTACATTT" => "GTAC", "TACG", "ACGT", "CGTA", "GTAC", "TACA", "ACAT", "CATT", "ATTT"
```

as your use of `str.count` seems to imply. Be aware, if it is the latter, `str.count` only counts **non-overlapping** instances - so `"AAAAAAA".count("AAAA")` returns 1 instead of the 4 you might have expected!

---

```
# assumes Python 2.7

from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import Counter
from itertools import izip, product, tee

def get_aligned_quads(seq, length=4):
    args = [iter(seq)] * length
    return (''.join(letters) for letters in izip(*args))

def get_unaligned_quads(seq, length=4):
    args = tee(iter(seq), length)
    for steps,arg in enumerate(args):
        for step in range(steps):
            next(arg, None)
    return (''.join(letters) for letters in izip(*args))

all_quads = [''.join(seq) for seq in product("ACGT", repeat=4)]

def quad_freq(sequence, aligned=True):
    get_quads = get_aligned_quads if aligned else get_unaligned_quads
    counts    = {quad:[] for quad in all_quads}

    for i,record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse(sequence, 'fasta')):
        for quad in all_quads:
            counts[quad].append(0)
        for quad in get_quads(record.seq):
            counts[quad][i] += 1
    return counts

print(quad_freq("$foo"))
```

**Edit:** I converted all_quads to a list - should be a little faster;

I also did a bit of simulation, and found that (assuming uniform-random inputs) using .count under-reports gene counts by about 1.049%. Obviously some types of quads are more affected than others:

Quads which are 4-the-same ("AAAA") are under-reported by 1/4 (25%) - that is, every time they are followed by the same letter again. This affects 4 / 256 quads, resulting in a reduction of 0.39% of the total gene count.

Quads which are 2-pairs ("ATAT") are under-reported by 1/16 (6.25%) - every time they are followed by the same pair of letters again. This affects 12 / 256 quads (omitting those which are also 4-the-same), resulting in a reduction of 0.29% of the total gene count.

Quads in which the first letter is the same as the last ("AGTA") are under-reported by 1/64 (1.56%) - every time they are followed by the first three letters again. This affects 60 / 256 quads (omitting those which are also 4-the-same), resulting in a reduction of 0.37% of the total gene count. Note that there is no overlap between (2-pairs - 4-the-same) and (first-and-last - 4-the-same).

Quads which do not match any of the above are not affected; this is the remaining 180 / 256 quads.

Comment: Thanks, @Hugh Bothwell, for noting that .count only gives aligned word counts.  I'm actually going to need the unaligned version, which your script offers.. 
However, I'm getting the key error:

    File "Untitled 5.py", line 27, in quad_freq
        counts[quad][i] += 1
    KeyError: 'ATAA'"

Comment: My mistake: I was returning ie ('A', 'T', 'A', 'A') from all_quads() instead of 'ATAA'. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand it, you have one word, say:

"GTACATTTCATGATTT"

Which gives you:

{'GTAC' : 1, 'ATTT': 2, 'CATG': 1}

So then if you see another word, say:

"GTACAATC"

You'd now have:

{'GTAC' : [1, 1], 'ATTT' : [2, 0], 'CATG' : [1, 0], 'AATC' : [0, 1]}

And so on? I'll edit my response if I misunderstood. Anyway, this should do it:

```
from itertools import product

strings = ["GTACATTTCATGATTT", "GTACAATC"]

count_dict = {}
for poss_word in product('ATCG', repeat=4):
    count_dict["".join(poss_word)] = [0] * len(strings)

for index, string in enumerate(strings):
    while string:
        word = string[:4]
        count_dict[word][index] += 1
        string = string[4:]
```

With things obviously extracted out to functions and what not.